# How to use plupload in Codeigniter based blog post and image gallery

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, gallery, blogs

I am trying to use plupload with Codeigniter for multi image uploads to my blog module and gallery module. But couldn't analyse how to use it with Codeigniter with HMVC. Can you give some idea with example. i couldn't decide how to create model and how to create modal and view for it. I couldn't understand how i could make it possible such that i can use it as image uploader, file/ image uploader in blog form and image uploader in gallery form such that it save files to uploads/blog folder if used within blog module, save images to uploads/galleryname and if used only as uploader it saves images and files to upload folder

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know how to setup HMVC. I am asking here that how can I setup plupload with my codeigniter app with HMVC

Answer (score 1):

### Modules

You can pass as many parameters as you like in 'Modules::run' method.
For your blog, just pass a reference to the type of image your uploading.

```
// include in your blog post
<?php echo Modules::run('module/controller/method', 'blog'); ?>

// include wherever you desire
<?php echo Modules::run('module/controller/method'); ?> //default param is "image"
```

### Controller Parameters

```
class someController extends CI_Controller
{

    protected $_uploadPath;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->uploadPath = ''; // path to images folder
    }

    public function upload($parameter='image') // set a default
    {
        if($parameter == 'blog'){
            $this->_uploadPath = ''; //path to blog/images folder
        }

        //do upload
    }
}
```